# Отключение звука в android-приложении

Tags: аудио, android

В приложении имеется много звуков, есть checkbox, как сделать так, чтобы при установке true, звук не воспроизводился, во всем приложении?

Comment: Кто нибудь отзовитесь!

Answer (score 3):

Вообщем спасибо всем за ответы, заработал следующий способ

```
if(isChecked){
        audioManager =            (AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
        audioManager.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, false);
    }else{
        audioManager =    (AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
        audioManager.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, true);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Я бы замутил некий наблюдающий класс. В нем была бы функция check(), которая бы содержала в себе один единственный иф, типа:

```
public void check() {
    if (!checkbox){
        sound.stop();
    }
}
```

И вызывал бы его в общем цикле:

```
soundController.check();
```

По крайне мере, именно так я реализовал у себя в приложении.

Comment: MyNameIsWinner, опиши поподробнее свой способ пожалуйста